# Why does the iframe extend past the end of the page when 100% in height?

Tags: css, iframe, html

I have an iframe on my site in a div. I have set both to 100% in height I'm also using the blueprint framework hence `span-12 last` for the class. My question is why is there still a scroll bar on the site?

**CODE:**

```
<div id="friend_pane" style="background-color: #FF0000;height: 100%;" class="span-12 last">
<iframe id="friendpane_area" style="width: 515px; height: 100%" src="http://friendsconnect.org/friendpane/shell.php" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Rather than just extent as much as possible it goes past the bottom of the page and has a scroll bar. Why is it assuming this height?

**SNAPSHOT:**

[image]

iFrame in DIV marked in red.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should try remove the semi colon in the end of the style in the div element, it might be the thing causing the problem though I doubt that

Comment: Could you add a live link to that page? I recognize that site, so I must have seen it live before.

Comment: @OmerPT: That's definitely irrelevant.

Comment: Also try checking if they both are not placed inside a bigger div, because when you use 100% it extends to 100% of the container, not the page itself, thus if the div containing them is bigger than the page itself the stuff inside will also expand to be bigger

Comment: This is FOR http://friendsconnect.org/ but the page with the problem is currently offline

Comment: What's the whole page html though (not just #friend_pane div)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things you could try, make sure `html { height: 100% }` first, then

```
iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```

or

```
<iframe id="friendpane_area" style="width: 515px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden" scrolling="no" src="http://friendsconnect.org/friendpane/shell.php" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't think `overflow: hidden` on the `iframe` could ever help. The `iframe` will never overflow, will it? It *might* help to stick it on `<div id="friend_pane">`.

Comment: If the `overflow: hidden` doesn't work on the iframe, the `scrolling="no"` should work but I don't know a reason why it wouldn't. Setting it to the div instead could be the answer though

Comment: scrolling="no" was the only thing that worked for me.